# Opening the jquery UI dialog inside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div#test` , with which i bind a `dblclick event to opens a jquery ui dialog`, now i want to open

that `dialog inside a floating div` ( means a div whose position is absolute and placed on the

center of the screen) when the `dblclick event triggers` on `div#test` something like :

```
           line #1     $("#test").trigger("dblclick"); => open the dialog 

           line #2     $("floatingdiv").html("I want to open the dialog inside

                        this div after executing the line #1);
```

Help me? Thanks.

Comment: This sounds simply like a modal dialog to me. In other words, simply open another modal above the first one. Is there something different?

Comment: yes it is jquery Ui dialog, but don`t want to open it on other elements, i want to open it inside a div, when we trigger the event which opens that dialog

Comment: SO, you simply use the `open:` event of the first dialog?  I am perplexed as to what exactly is your challenge here. http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#event-open

Comment: yeah `open` event is there but how will i open it inside the div? (I want something similar to the `target` attribute of iframe, is there any such kind of thing in jquery ui dialog? )

Comment: Are we confusing the event (open of the first dialog - it IS a dialog according to your question) and setting the position option of the second dialog relative to the first dialogs position?  Perhaps you need to rephrase your question with the example code (all of it) related to the two dialogs as well as the exact code you use to open each - or at least what you have tried to this juncture.  You would not open/position something "inside" but simply position "relative to" other elements.

Comment: I want $("#test").html($("dialog").dialog('open')); this works fine but when the dialog is opened by triggering the `dblclick event` then it open`s outside the `html() of div#test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First put `test` div inside `floatingdiv`.

```
$("#test .ui-dialog-content").bind("dialogopen", function() {  
    // Reposition dialog, 'this' refers to the element the even occurred on.
    $(this).parent('div').css('position', 'relative');
});
```